# Align input in div

Tags: html, css, input

I have such html code:

```
<div class="one1">
<div class="one">
<input class="two" name="user[email]" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required="required" type="email">
</div>
</div>​
```

and css

```
.one1{
    background-color: #000;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.one{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #cecece;
    width:180px;
    height: 200px;
}
.two{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
​
```

But why input is little bit to big on right border? How to do it clear as it's one div? (also there will be rounded borders and shadow)

Here:

> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7fXhv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best is to remove 1px on each side Left and Right of you input and to set it manualy instead of 100%

```
.two{
    width: 178px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you remove the `margin` and `padding` but input has a `border` also. So try to add `border:none` for the `input`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7fXhv/16/)

Comment: @brabertaser1992 then you can only change the width.

Answer (score 0):

Because its including the border width.  Try:

```
.two{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the border added by the user agent stylesheet. Add `border: 0;` to the `two` class.

```
.two{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the border at 1 px go for:

```
.two {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari */
}
```

The browser is calculating the width (100%) of the input based on content + padding, you want instruct the broswer to include the borders as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css property

```
input.two{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari */
}
```